# Как выделить память для массива структур и реализовать работу со структурами через функцию?

Tags: c++, массивы, память, структуры, выделение-памяти

Никак не могу понять, каким образом можно выделить память для моего примера память (Структура УНИВЕРСИТЕТ с полями: название, адрес, телефон, количество факультетов, число студентов). И каким образом оформить функцию, к примеру, которая добавляет новый элемент в конец

```
struct university {
    string name  = "";
    string address = "";
    int phone_number = 0;
    int number_of_faculties = 0;
    int number_of_students = 0;
};

void print(int p);
void Screen();
void FindElement(int p);
void SortStruct();
void EditStruct(int p);
void pushback();
void erase(int p);
void insert();
void OnFile();
void FromFile();

int main() {
    university* array = nullptr;
    int size = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
university* array = new university[количество элементов в массиве];
```